# any guidance to balance between law of demeter and too much interface duplication?

Tags: c++, code-duplication

I have noticed that when you are following good software engineering principles (such as the law of demeter) often times you end up duplicating function *interfaces*.

For example, the law of Demeter results in writing "wrapper functions" that simply delegate work to an internal object of the class.

Code example:

```
class A{
public:
    void doSomething(){
        internalObj_.doSomething();
    }
private:
    SomeType internalObj_;
}
```

If class A has a lot of private objects, its interface can get quite huge.

Question:
When is the duplication of interface justified? In other words, is it ok to duplicate 10 functions but no more? Does the number of functions not matters, is there another metric by which I can "sense" when I have done enough function interface duplication?

Please give me some reasoning with your answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you described is taking the law of demeter to the extreme, and is a code smell.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @RSahu when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: afaik it is a well known disadvantage of the law of demeter, that you end up with lots of wrapping and duplicating interfaces. Thus, if you want to follow the law, it is ok to have this effect. On the other hand, if you want to avoid this effect, then strictly appliying the law maybe isnt the best choice.

Comment: @mods I have edited the question to make it more concrete, can you reopen it please?

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case you cited, it's nearly a certainty that if you were to explicitly use `inline` the compiler will inline the wrapper, resulting in no runtime penalty.

The only expense here is the additional typing work/redundancy/etc... Which, in the grand scheme of things, gives you additional flexibility in terms of reimplementing the public interface to your class, if it becomes necessary to have the class implement the functionality itself, instead of delegating it to someone else.

Comment: _"to explicitly use inline the compiler will inline the wrapper, resulting in no runtime penalty."_ Any decent modern c++ compiler will do this anyway.

Comment: I think that gcc without the -O2 flag will not inline even something like that, in order to aid in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, the law of Demeter results in writing "wrapper functions" that simply delegate work to an internal object of the class.

If this happens, it is often the smell of bad design. Abstractions generally provide a higher level interface and don't simply aggregate their internals.

> If class A has a lot of private objects, its interface can get quite huge.

If a class has a lot of private objects that's often the smell of bad design. You should aim for the [`Single Responsibilty Priciple`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) which will typically keep the number of members low.

Duplicating an interface is most common when you separate a public interface from a private interface, where the duplication is used to decouple.